# SmartCloud OAuth2.0 Registering applications

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, ibm-connections

I am busy writing an mobile application that connects with IBM SmartCloud. Since I want to use OAuth 2.0 I find it difficult to handle the Secret Key and the Client ID.

Since I have to Register the Application within the IBM SmartCloud console, and copy the Client ID and Secret Key to the App I am creating... Well that ain't the biggest problem, but when someone wants to use my app on another environment he doesn't have the same Secret Key and Client Id.

What is the best way to deal with this, because I want to make it usable for others, and not only for my use.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to the ibmsbt.openntf.org - the sources include directory includes a project for iOS. It's tested with IBM Connections On Premises

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Social%20Business%20Toolkit%20SDK/releases/F07E34DFDDA6C06686257C6B006C6393

The project uses a callback to a custom PROTOCOL/URL : ibmsbt://myapp?code=

For IBM Connections/SmartCloud, you'll want to register an OAuth2 Key.
When you register you'll want to register your application, ibmsbt://myapp/

Then You can use these endpoints and parameters:

https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth2/token/manage/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=app_20085940_1384885218905&callback_uri=ibmsbt%3A%2F%2Fmyapp%2Fcallback

https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/authorizeToken?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN